# error when adding user to wheel group in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, terminal, sudo, yum

**I am trying to grant sudo privileges to a user of a CentOS 7 devbox by typing `gpasswd -a user wheel`, but the attempt is failing.  What am I doing wrong?**

Here is what I typed:

I discovered that the user is not in the wheel group as follows:

```
[user@localhost git]$ sudo yum install git
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: 
user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I then logged in as root and typed the following to add the user to the wheel group:

```
[user@localhost git]$ su -
Password: 
Last login: Thu Aug 20 17:11:31 PDT 2015 on pts/0
[root@localhost ~]# gpasswd -a user wheel
Adding user user to group wheel
[root@localhost ~]# exit
logout
```

I finally tried to use the sudo command again but it failed as follows:

```
[user@localhost git]$ sudo yum install git
[sudo] password for user: 
user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
[user@localhost git]$
```

Comment: What does `groups` show for the user? Group changes usually require logging out and back in to see them.

Comment: No, you just need a new session, which if under X11 might require logging out of X11 and back in. Or, SSH to localhost, that should create a new session (for that SSH session), among other such tricks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group changes on unix are not recognized by existing login sessions; assuming, say, a Linux system with the `usermod` command:

```
$ groups
user
$ sudo usermod -G wheel $USER
...
$ grep user /etc/group | grep wheel
wheel:x:10:user
$ groups
user
```

To see the group change, any existing sessions (e.g. SSH, X11, etc.) must be exited, and a new session made (e.g. open a new SSH connection, login in again via X11, etc):

```
$ ssh localhost
...
$ groups
user wheel
```

... or you could reboot the box, which would mandate new sessions be created once the host comes back up.

Comment: note that you could also just run "newgrp wheel" in an existing login session

Answer (score 2):

Your existing login session didn't load with the wheel group membership. Now that it's been granted, you can incorporate it by entering:

```
newgrp wheel
```

... without having to log out or reboot.